# JMeter: Polling for a simple HTTP request

Tags: jmeter

please could you give me an example on how to use a while loop to keep checking (polling) if my HTTP GET request (REST api call) has returned the successful response or not. Say for example, third attempt brings the successful response and I come out of the loop, How do I measure the time it has taken?

Answer (score 0):

Please use While controller:

1) init counter JSR223 Sampler --> vars.put("counter","1");

2) while controller

3) inside while controller put your HTTP get

4) put a regex to retrieve what you are looking for (or JSON extractor)

5) Another JSR223 Assertion to check the result of what you retreived

if(!detail.equals("REGEX_FAILED")){
......
}
7) timer so you wait

8) increment counter